# Why it appears that my variable is not defined if I defined it above in python

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python and I would like to know why even if I defined my variable counterofplays above the function it is not being recognized in it.

```
counterofplays = 0  # this variable should be defined below

def tiktaktoe():
    while playing:
        isdigit = False
        inRange = False
        while not isdigit or not inRange:
            playable = True 
            print(firstchoice,"turn")
            index = input("Choose the index:\n" +
                        "1 | 2 | 3\n" +
                        "4 | 5 | 6\n" +
                        "7 | 8 | 9\n")

            if index.isdigit():
                isdigit = True
                index = int(index)
                if index in range(1,4) and row1[index-1][0] == ' ':
                    inRange = True
                    row1[index-1] = firstchoice if index == 3 else firstchoice + " | "
                    counterofplays += 1 # and here it marks error
                elif index in range(4,7) and row2[index-4][0] == ' ':
                    inRange = True
                    row2[index-4] = firstchoice if index == 6 else firstchoice + " | "                
                    counterofplays += 1
                elif index in range(7,10) and row3[index-7][0] == ' ':
                    inRange = True
                    row3[index-7] = firstchoice if index == 9 else firstchoice + " | "                
                    counterofplays += 1
                else:
                    inRange = False
                    playable = False
            else:
                isdigit = False
                playable = False
                print("You've to choose a number")
                sleep(1.3)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full Traceback?

Comment: The line `counterofplays += 1` is inside the function, and since you're setting the value, Python assumes it is a local variable, only in scope for the function, not in the global scope. However, since it hasn't been defined previously in the function, you get that error. Changing a global value outside a function is generally not a very good idea (although there are cases where it makes sense), but if you need to you want to add `global counterofplays` to the start of the function.

Comment: @Grismar The thing is that I come from Java and I didn't understand why this happens in many cases exercises that I've been doing until yesterday and now that I know, it seems weird for me that if I define a variable above a function and then want to change its value in that function I have to do it declaring the variable as global unlike Java, so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try defining `counterofplays` Directly inside`TikTakToe()` as `global` And it shouldn’t cause any problem. Since it doesn’t seem that you use that variable outside of the aforementioned function you could also not set it as `global`